# grid binding to DynamicResource XmlDataProvider is not updating after xml changes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, xaml

Below code is successfully adding node in `testdata.xml` after clicking add button, but unable to refresh the tree in `grid1`.
xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="XmlDataTree.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="XmlData Tree Test"
        Width="250"
        Height="350" >
    
       <Window.Resources>

        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmldata"
                         Source="testdata.xml"
                         XPath="/root" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Node"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="0"
                           Text="Node:" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="leaf">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="0"
                           Text="Leaf:" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="root"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}">
            <TextBlock Margin="0"
                       Text="ROOT" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

  
    <!--
        This sets the DataContext of the Grid to the XmlProvider
        with a key of xmldata (set above in the Window.Resources
        section).
    -->
    <Grid Name="grid0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid DataContext="{DynamicResource xmldata}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="grid1">
            <!--
            Setting the ItemsSource to "{Binding}" causes the TreeView
            to use the Grid's DataContext as its source, and the
            templates describe h        ow each tag is to be displayed and
            handled, in case the node has descendent nodes.
        -->
            <TreeView Name="dirTree"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Name="Add" Grid.Row="1" Width="50" Height="20" Content="Add Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="AddNode"></Button>
            <TextBox Height="23" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="textBox1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" />
  
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

cs file code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlDataTree
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void xmladdnode()
        {
            string filename = @"testdata.xml";

            //create new instance of XmlDocument
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            //load from file
            //doc.Load(filename);

            //XmlDocument doc3 = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(filename);
            XmlNode root1 = doc.DocumentElement;
            //Create a new attrtibute.  
            XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("Node");
            XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
            attr.Value = "6";
            elem.Attributes.Append(attr);
            root1.InsertAfter(elem, root1.LastChild);
          
            doc.Save(filename);
            XmlDataProvider oProv = grid1.DataContext as XmlDataProvider;
            oProv.Refresh();

        }

        private void AddNode(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button clicked = (Button)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("Button's name is: " + clicked.Name);
            xmladdnode();
         
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Move the object  "XmlDataProvider oProv" to global space so you can do a refresh inside the AddNode method.